# Android login form using mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, authentication, android-ksoap2

I have developed a Login form.

This is my webservice code:

```
public class Login {
    public String authentication(String userName,String password){

    String retrievedUserName = "";
    String retrievedPassword = "";
    String status = "";
    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androidlogin","root","chathura");
        PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '"+userName+"'");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()){
            retrievedUserName = result.getString("username");
            retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
        }

        if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)){
            status = "Success!";
        }

        else{
            status = "Login fail!!!";
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
    }

}
```

This is my android code:

```
try{
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    String status = response.toString();
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
    result.setText(response.toString());

    if(status.equals("Success!")){

        //   ADD  to save  and  read next time
        String strUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
        String strPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0){

            //  showToast("Enter Your Name");
            userName.setError( "username is required!" );
            isUserValidated = false;
        }
        if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0){

            //  showToast("Enter Your Password");
            isPasswordValidated = false;
            userPassword.setError( "password is required!" );
        } 
        if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated){

            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidLoginExampleActivity.this,TabBarSimple.class);
            intent.putExtra("login",userName.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);           
        }
    }

    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidLoginExampleActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){ 
    //
}

}
}
```

**my current o/p** is:

- If I enter the correct login details, it displays "success" message and after that goes to the next Activity
- If I enter the wrong login details, it displays "login fail" message.

**Wish to need the o/p** is:

- If I enter the correct login details, it should directly go to the next Activity and shouldn't display any success message.
- If I enter the wrong login details, the "login fail" message should be displayed.

Please help me with this. How can i develop this?

Comment: what you have tried.! you should post the code, that you had tried, then ask for the problem that you encounter.

Comment: remove the code that displays the success message. thats it. it will directly shift to the next activity after login success.

Comment: what is your **AndroidLoginExampleActivity** and **tabBarActivity**

Comment: this is my AndroidLoginExampleActivity:http://pastie.org/5077238           this is my tabBarActivity:http://pastie.org/5077243

Comment: SO you want to open the **tabBarActivity** when the login is successfull. and stay at the **AndroidLogin..** , when login fails. remove the _Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidLoginExampleActivity.class);_ code from the **else** part and just show some **AlertDialog** or **Toast** displaying failure message.

Comment: you dont only want to use alert dialog in login form or you dont want them in your enitre application.?

Comment: you can use an EditText and set the value of that EditText to **Login Failed** in case of failure.

Comment: why am used EditText here.i can't understand this solution.please explain more clearly.thanks

Comment: Can you please show where and how you are printing the **Login faied** message, which you want to remove.

Comment: show the failed message using textview before on username textview

Comment: Hi where are you keeping the php file even i have the same code but when i type the address localhost:8080/check.php i get a 404 error..Please help i am new to android

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, you dont want to use toast or alert dialog in your application to show login failed message, so you can use Textview to show the message, for this, you should mention a textView along with the Password EditText field, with any name say, **PasswordMessage**.

Now, try to use the following code,

```
TextView PasswordMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PasswordMessage);
if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidLoginExampleActivity.this,TabBarSimple.class);
    intent.putExtra("login",userName.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    PasswordMessage.setText("Login Failed, Please enter valid Username or Password");
}
```